# React Native - Edit other component's state

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to edit other componenet's state by running function which checks if the current state of the app is active, Which means it runs each time the app come to the forground.

```
let d = new Date().getHours();
let title = messages[`_${d}`].message;

function getAppState() {
  AppState.addEventListener("change", (state) => {
    if(state == "active") {
      d = new Date().getHours();
      title = messages[`_${d}`].message;
      // App.setState({ text: title }); **Not working!
      console.log(title);
    }
  });
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { text: title };
    getAppState();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <StatusBar hidden={ true } />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to change text's value according to the hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an environment to test this but I would do it like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: title
    };

    // Bind updateTile() so `this` corresponds tho the react component and things
    // like `this.setState()` are available. Otherwise `this` would be `AppState`
    this.updateTitle = this.updateHour.bind(this);

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Listen for the event
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this.updateTitle);
  }

  updateTitle(state) {
    if (state == "active") {
      const d = new Date().getHours();
      const title = messages[`_${d}`].message;
      this.setState({
        text: title
      });
      console.log(title);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View >
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Text style = {styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View >
    );
  }
}
```

If you wanted `updateTitle()` to be another function and is not part of the `Component` I would do this:

```
const updateComponentTitle = state => {
  if (state == "active") {
    const d = new Date().getHours();
    const title = messages[`_${d}`].message;
    this.setState({
      text: title
    });
    console.log(title);
  }
}


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: title
    };

    // Bind updateTile() so `this` corresponds tho the react component and things
    // like `this.setState()` are available. Otherwise `this` would be `AppState`
    this.updateTitle = udpateComponentTitle.bind(this);

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Listen for the event
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this.updateTitle);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View >
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Text style = {styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View >
    );
  }
```

}